# Determine the language script of a string

Tags: c#, .net, string, localization

I have to verify the language strings for localization, looking for a way to know the written language script (characters) of the string in application. Not sure how to automate this task.

What I need is to check the script of the string e.g. If its Cyrillic, or Devanagari or Chinese or Latin.

E.g.

If I check 'आपका स्वागत है' string, it should return that its a Devanagari script

Or '欢迎' should return that its a Chinese script

I was thinking of using/maintaining a predefined set of characters to test against, but wondering if there is any sophisticated way of doing this and make it more generalized.

Comment: You could try: http://ntextcat.codeplex.com/

Comment: You can estimate the language by Unicode Character Range http://jrgraphix.net/research/unicode_blocks.php . More sophistated approach is to use some kind of Language Detection API (e.g. Google Translate API)

Comment: @TimSchmelter: This sounds interesting and pretty simple, Nice library. I will give it a try. Thanks

Comment: @DmitryBychenko: The character range is also a good approach, will try to build a simple process with this. Thanks. Can't really use Google API in this case.

Comment: I'd recommend to specify language by translator. To example, if you have text files, then file name can be `en-US.txt` or `ru-Ru.txt`. Or perhaps the first line in this file can be `LNG=English` or `Language=en-UK`, whatever you feel is better. Detecting language could be tricky, especially if its a *dialect* (uses same alphabet). Perhaps you can try to use Google to detect text language for you or similar vocabulary-based approaches, as they are more accurate.

Comment: @Sinatr: Indeed, that's correct and that is how I am getting the files from translators. Although, I am doing this to validate the files. There can always be human mistakes and hence, it would be better to recheck and validate what we are implementing as the translation instead of using it blindly trusting that the files must be correct at all.